# how to set image width and height in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In html I just do `<img src="x.jpg" width="1px" height="2px">` how about in vb.net. Is there an easy way to do this. When you are viewing the image through the picture box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you display the image? If you load an image into the `Image` property of a `PictureBox` you can use the `SizeMode` property to [stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx) the image to the size of the PictureBox. You can then set the width and height of the PictureBox.

```
PictureBox1.Load("image.png")
PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Stretch
PictureBox1.Size = New Size(width, height)
```